# Como padronizar formato de DateTime para todos os campos do tipo sem utilizar DisplayFor nem EditorFor no MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Em muitos casos na aplicação temos que usar algo tipo:

```
@Html.Raw(item.data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

não pode ser `DisplayFor` nem `EditorFor` em nenhum caso e temos que mostrar o formato brasileiro de data. Como padronizar isso de uma só vez utilizando o MVC?

Comment: Qual o motivo de não poder usar `DisplayFor` nem `EditorFor`, sendo que usá-los é a maneira correta?

Comment: Pensei que daria erro coloca-los dentro de WebGrid, mas vi que funciona.

Comment: @TonAngelo tudo bem, gostaria de saber **(se puder)** qual era o cenário do seu problema, porque, de certo modo quando é configurado corretamente a aplicação muitas coisas são implícitas e nem precisam ser configurado. Eu também gostaria de ver na sua pergunta esse `model` e também pergunta se você configurou o globalization da sua app? Se puder responder talvez muitas coisas pode ser esclarecidas, mesmo tendo se posicionado em um resposta!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Eu peguei o sistema recentemente, a pessoa que havia iniciado saiu da empresa e não sei como que ela gerou as classes do banco de dados, nenhum tipo DateTime do model tem DataType definido e como o banco tem muitas tabelas, seria inviável sair trocando tudo.
O Web.Config consta <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />, mas mesmo assim se não passar formatação continua o formato americano.

Comment: @TonAngelo retire do globalization `enableClientBasedCulture="false"` faz um teste ou coloque `enableClientBasedCulture="true"` vai perceber que vai ficar formatado corretamente. Eu te entendo ... !!! faz essa configuração. e vai ter muitas diferenças!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic se por um acaso o computador do cliente estiver com SO em outro idioma, isso manteria em português?

Comment: @TonAngelo o que vale é o que está na sua aplicação, todos que acessam o seu site (app) tem a linguagem pt-BR ou seja portugues. Sim o idioma é o que você configura, mudou alguma coisa?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic alterou sim, de forma global isso quase resolveria meu problema, eu ainda tenho que definir para não exibir os segundos em todos os DateTime. Mas já agradeço demais. Esse pequeno detalhe no Web.Config ajudou muito.

Comment: @TonAngelo ... !!! perceba que se fosse configurado corretamente, nem isso precisa fazer, mas, não é culpa sua e sim de quem desenvolveu primeiro... Cara boa sorte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Como padronizar isso de uma só vez utilizando o MVC?

Usando `DisplayFor` e `EditorFor`. Qualquer coisa diferente disso, considerando apenas o Razor, é incorreto.

Outra coisa é a respeito de utilizar apenas a data, e não a hora (`DateTime`, no caso, tem os dois componentes). Neste caso, decore seu *Model* com o tipo de dados ([`[DataType]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)) correspondente ao formato apenas data (`DataType.Date`):

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class SeuModel
{
    ...
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Lembrando que isto gera um `<input type="date" />`, e não um `<input type="text" />`, que não possui formatação de datas pelo padrão do navegador.

Comment: Esse do DataType.Date eu passei batido, estava fazendo um if (Model.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == 0) para definir caso seja apenas Date.
Valeu pela dica!

Comment: Aproveitando, [veja aqui como funciona o site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para tirar maior proveito dele. Bons estudos ;)

Answer (score 2):

Olá eu acho uma prática melhor criar um componente que gere o text na tela.

Exemplo:

```
namespace IM.Framework.MVC
{
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    public static partial class IMHelper
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString IMInputDate(this HtmlHelper html, string Id, string Caption, string PlaceHolder, int Size, DateTime Value)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(GeraDiv(new string[] { "input-control", "text", "span" + Size.ToString() }));
            sb.Append(IMLabel(html, Id, Caption));
            sb.Append(String.Format("<input type='text' id='{0}' placeholder='{1}' value='{2}' class='inputPadrao inputDate' />",
                Id, PlaceHolder, Value));
            sb.Append(FechaTag("div"));

            return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Na View utilize no lugar de

```
@Html.Raw(item.data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

utilize:

```
@IMHelper.IMInputDate("id_do_campo", "Título", 10, item.data)
```

Lembrando que no IMInputDate utilizo código que depende de outras funções não disponibilizadas aqui. Mas a ideia é apenas dar uma "Luz".

Comment: O comentário do Cigano na minha pergunta me fez pensar melhor no meu problema, mas eu realmente vou manter essa sua resposta salva nos meus arquivos porque gostei bastante. Obrigado.